# django redirect is applied to all projects directly

Tags: django, google-chrome, redirect

I was studying mozilla django tutorial and in between that I came across one point where I have to redirect the url ' ' to '/catalog/' with permanent = True.
Now I have one new project (another project in different directory ) with django-admin and gave the command of manage.py runserver (notice I haven't made any changes in this project) the url '' is automatically being redirect to '/catalog/' in chrome it works fine in opera mini though.

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably not a Django issue, but due to Chrome caching certain requests. You could try a hard refresh of the page:
https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

Unless the redirect is being handled by some unusual Javascript (and you are doing this in Django so probably not), you probably just need to refresh the page. Hold the shift key while clicking on the refresh button in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is because chrome has cached this particular redirect and uses it without checking with the server. You can get rid of this by clearing your browser cache - but you might not want to do this because you'll lose other data too. Instead, right click on the page in question and go to developer tools (or hit F12). Go to the Network tab and tick "Disable cache". Now refresh the page without the redirected part of the url, and the page should load correctly. Now close developer tools and it should continue to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the browser history(going to Advanced mode and selecting everything).